# How to check ion-checkbox from database

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this ionic tag already populated and with all items unchecked:

```
            <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="categoria in listaCategorias"
                           ng-model="categoria.checked"
                           ng-checked="categoria.checked"
                           ng-change="recuperarServicos(categoria)">
                           {{ categoria.nmCategoria }}
            </ion-checkbox>
```

And here my controller code that has a list of 'categoria ids':

```
//here I have the ids recovered from database that I split into an array of ids
var idsCategoria = $scope.meuanuncio.idsCategoria.trim().split(',');

if($scope.listaCategorias.length > 0)
{
    //for each item in my listaCategorias (used in ng-repeat)
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listaCategorias.length; i++) {

        var item = $scope.listaCategorias[i];

        //I compare id from each item with my list recovered from database
        if(idsCategoria.indexOf($scope.listaCategorias[i].idCategoria) != -1)
        {
            //If the item id exist in database list, I check the item
            item.checked = true;

            // Below there are other ways that I tried to use
            // $scope.listaCategorias[i].Selected = true;
            // $scope.listaCategorias[i].checked = true;
            $scope.listaCategorias[0].checked = true;
        }
    }
};
```

But I can´t do my ion-checkbox item checked.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a flag, like isChecked = true or isChecked = false

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-model="categoria.checked"
```

looks fine, don't think you need the  ng-checked though.

```
 var item = $scope.listaCategorias[i];
item.checked = true;
```

Nope, the item gets lost through the loop. I see you were trying with:

```
$scope.listaCategorias[i].checked = true;
```

Did you get an error or something? Because this looks like the way to do it.

Maybe try looping on a div around the ion-checkbox? aka

```
<div ng-repeat="categoria in listaCategorias">
   <ion-checkbox ng-model="categoria.checked"
                 ng-change="recuperarServicos(categoria)">
                 {{ categoria.nmCategoria }}
   </ion-checkbox> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jonasty. I put the div around and I changed the item, using your suggestion. Nothing happened !!! And I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<div ng-repeat="categoria in listaCategorias track by $index">
      <ion-item class="item item-checkbox">
           <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="categoria.checked" ng-change="recuperarServicos(categoria)">
           </label>
         {{categoria.nmCategoria}}
      </ion-item>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.recuperarServicos = function(categoria){
        if(categoria.selected && ($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(categoria.name) < 0)){
          $scope.selectedItems.push(categoria.name);
        }else{
            $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(categoria.name), 1);
        }
    };
```

hope this helps you..in someway..!

Comment: Hi. My problem is the path coming from database. Your example is good, but my problem is how to check my 'categorias' when I have a list of 'categorias' id (listaCategorias) and I need to check all items when loading the view. Did you understand it now ?

Comment: Did u mean, like.. U hav 10 categories.. And ur category are 4..so..when view is loaded.. Only 4 categories should be checked and u can also update more by selecting more..! M I right..!?

Comment: Yes !!! Exactly. I am getting data from database and populate this item and other form fields with those data, to user update.
So the 'categorias' items will have only the database data items checked, and the user will be able to change it on the form.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was when I attribute my array of items to the $scope.listaCategorias.

I was doing that:

$scope.listaCategorias = listaCategorias;

But I need to do that:

$scope.listaCategorias.push.apply($scope.listaCategorias, listaCategorias);

I was building an array with the checked attribute inside, but when I associate my built list, I was associating the first one, which has not the checked attribute setted.

Let me show my code now.

My view :

```
        <div ng-repeat="item in listaCategorias track by $index">
              <ion-item class="item item-checkbox">
                   <label class="checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="item.checked" ng-change="recuperarServicos(item)">
                   </label>
                  {{ item.nmCategoria }}
              </ion-item>
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
//here I get all my 'categorias' from datatable
listaCategorias = appFactory.recuperarCategorias();

//If list is not null go ahead   
if(listaCategorias != null) {

    //split into an array all my 'categoria' ids
    var idsCategoria = $scope.meuanuncio.idsCategoria.split(',');

    //if list has items go ahead
    if(listaCategorias.length > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < listaCategorias.length; i++) {

            //if 'categoria' id exists in datatable list set true, else false
            if(idsCategoria.indexOf(listaCategorias[i].idCategoria) != -1) {
                listaCategorias[i].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                listaCategorias[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    };

    //Here is the point !!! I need to load my $scope variable this way to build all my items correctly
    $scope.listaCategorias.push.apply($scope.listaCategorias, listaCategorias);

}
```